# Return all <p> and <h> tags with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm trying to return the title, H tags, and P tags in a webpage using apps script in Google Spreadsheet.

I tried this function but it doesn't seem to retrieve some tags depending on the source.

```js
function myfunction(url) {
  var _options = {
    method: "GET"
  };

  try {
    var _response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, _options);
    var _regexp =  /<title[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/title>|.*<h[1-6][^>]*?>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>|<p[^>]*?>.*?<\/p>/gi;
        var _tag = _response.getContentText().match(_regexp);

    return _tag;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

For example [this site](https://mens.tasclap.jp/a1426) doesn't return the H1 tag.

I'm new to apps script and regex, and it would be great if I can get some hints.

THANK YOU!

Comment: I think this is because `.` in regex doesn't include line breaks. But line breaks can be included by replacing `.` with `(.|\n|\r)`. So the whole expression would look like:
`/<title[^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/title>|.*<h[1-6][^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/h[1-6]>|<p[^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/p>/gi`

Comment: @Guac HO.LY.SHIT. This just saved my day. and all my coworkers' day. Thank you so much. Noted for future use.

Comment: @Guac Consider adding a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the updated regex expression the code would look like:

```
function myfunction(url) {
  var _options = {
    method: "GET"
  };

  try {
    var _response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, _options);
    var _regexp =  /<title[^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/title>|.*<h[1-6][^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/h[1-6]>|<p[^>]*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/p>/gi;
        var _tag = _response.getContentText().match(_regexp);

    return _tag;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

The initial problem was that `.` in regex doesn't include line breaks. This was fixed by replacing `.` with `(.|\n|\r)`, which includes line breaks.